# cant compile glib-2.9.6, Hundreds of multiple definition errors

Tags: compiling, glib

I have build error by trying to compile glib-2.9.6 on Ubuntu 22.04

```
/usr/bin/ld: .libs/gatomic.o: in function `g_bit_nth_lsf':
/home/user/Development/glib-2.9.6/glib/../glib/gutils.h:277: multiple definition of `g_bit_nth_lsf'; .libs/gasyncqueue.o:/home/user/Development/glib-2.9.6/glib/../glib/gutils.h:277: first defined here
```

And hundreds more of them. I don't know why it occurs multiple definitions errors?

Comment: glib-2.9.6 is *ancient* I think? you may need to add `-fcommon` to your `CFLAGS` - see for example [Porting to GCC 10](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-10/porting_to.html)

Comment: Is there a `configure` script you should have run? Are there `README` or `INSTALL` files to read? See https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/

Comment: To add to @steeldriver's comment: `glib-2.9` appears towards the bottom of the source release list (https://download.gnome.org/sources/glib/), since it's lex-sorted, which is why it can be mistaken for the most recent version. You'll need to visually look at the largest version number (`2.78` at this point i think) to get the latest.